# value of tan(x) as x approaches 90

Tags: trigonometry

SO I checked on my calculator and I was randomly searching values of:
tan(89.99)=5729.577
tan(89.999)=57295.77
tan(89.9999)=57297.79
(all values approx) and so on..

But when I checked this via taylor series it's not coming to such a value. Plus it is similar with cosec(x) tending to 0 etc.
So does this number hold some significance or its just a random number?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of radians, for small $t>0$,
$$\tan\left(\frac\pi 2-t\right)=\frac1{\tan t}\approx\frac1t.$$
If you are perverse enough to measure angles in degrees rather than radians,
then $(90-t)^\circ=\frac\pi 2-\frac{\pi t}{180}$ so
$$\tan(90-t)^\circ\approx\frac{180}{\pi t}.$$
So what does $180/\pi$ look like?

Comment: thank you so much. At this point I really feel dumb. God knows what I was thinking.